# Add a Margin in rems to Absolute Positioned and Transformed Element

Tags: html, css, transform

I have a set of absolute positioned elements, whose dimensions are measured in `rem`'s and which are align using `transform: translateX`.

I need to add a gap between the boxes of `1rem`, but the `margin-right` / `margin-left` properties aren't working and I can't seem to find a solution.

CodePen: https://codepen.io/pen/

CSS

```
.box {
  height: 6rem;
  width: 6rem;
  background: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
}

.box2 { transform: translateX(100%); background: red; }
.box3 { transform: translateX(200%); background: yellow; }
.box4 { transform: translateX(300%); }
```

HTML

```
<div class="box box1"></div>
<div class="box box2"></div>
<div class="box box3"></div>
<div class="box box4"></div>
```

Comment: I don't think you actually saved that pen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An absolutey positioned element's margins have no effect on other elements, so you have to change either the position settings to create space between them, or (in your case) apply `left`settings to them to further move them from their original position. However, you have to increase those for every element since this still relates to the original position which also is not affected by other elements: In my example I put 1rem on the second, 2rem on the third and 3rem on the 4th box to achieve 1 rem distance between them:

```css
html, body {
margin: 0;
}
.box {
  height: 6rem;
  width: 6rem;
  background: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
}

.box2 {
  left: 1rem;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  background: red;
}

.box3 {
  left: 2rem;
  transform: translateX(200%);
  background: yellow;
}

.box4 {
  left: 3rem;
  transform: translateX(300%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box box1"></div>
<div class="box box2"></div>
<div class="box box3"></div>
<div class="box box4"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the way you do that alignment is the best. If you must code with `transform` and because margin doesn't work on absolute elements, you can use `Left` or `calc()` property as below.
Why not use a `float` property or `display: flex` instead ?

```css
.box {height: 6rem;
width: 6rem;
background: blue;
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
}

.box2 {transform: translateX(calc(100% + 1rem)); background: red;}
.box3 {transform: translateX(calc(200% + 2rem)); background: yellow;}
.box4 {transform: translateX(calc(300% + 3rem));}
```

```html
<div class="box box1"></div>
<div class="box box2"></div>
<div class="box box3"></div>
<div class="box box4"></div>
```